# Can I display Modified Date for documents only (not folders) in a Document Library view?

Tags: content-type, calculated-column, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a document library in a SharePoint on premises site. I want to display the modified date of documents in the library, but folders show the modification date of the folder itself, not the most recently modified contents of the folder which I feel may confuse users. I've found solutions using workflows to update a custom column when items are added or modified; however, I don't have access to workflows on this server. I was thinking I might be able to create a custom calculated column that either displays only for documents and not for folders or detects that the item is a folder in the calculation.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you using classic experience or modern experience?

Comment: I believe the server version is 2013, modern experience is not available on the server. My organization started transitioning to SharePoint online earlier this year (no sunset for the server has been announced yet, but we are slowly moving existing sites).

Comment: Looks like I'll probably be transitioning this site to SharePoint Online soon.